# How to scroll UICollectionView by scrolling slider in Swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uislider

I want to make collectionView that scrolls, when user scrolls UISlider. I'm using UISlider with same number of values as collection. But it is not very smooth. My code:

```
let currentValue = Int(sender.value)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: currentValue, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

Maybe there is more efficient way to do this? Like scrolling by offset? But I don't know how to calculate values to do this by using method `collectionView.setContentOffset`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
self.collectionView.contentOffset.y += sender.value // sender is your UISlider
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but as I use your method, my collection just flies away. I think reason is that the value of slider is much lesser, then content offset – It's same as number of items, but height is different (I use vertical slider, so I changed x to y, of course)

Comment: @ArtemBoordak to control the speed, you may divide or multiply a constant with `sender.value`. I have also updated the answer.

Comment: I'm not certain which multiplayer would be proper, but, when I multiplied by height of cells in collectionView this worked pretty well. Thanks!